# Electron App Renderer Process Doesn't Execute

Tags: javascript, html, css, bash, electron

I try to run a very simple electron app on a remote server but I face the error:

```
$ npm run start

> my-electron-app@1.0.0 start
> electron .

[746079:0425/161022.653326:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[746079:0425/161022.653419:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
/data01/leon/fabian-desktop/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGABRT
```

What does the error mean and how can I solve it? Thanks...

I also tried `npx electron .` but it doesn't make any difference.